# Handle every exception in phoenix and implement an action after it

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I have an usual phoenix app. I want to track every exception in it by implementing `ExcetpionTracker.action` on it (action could be everything from json post up to mailer send). How can I do that?

P.S. I know that I can use `airbrake`, `honeybadger` and a lot of stuff like that, but I prefer not to use them.

Comment: You can create a plug with https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.ErrorHandler.html, plug that into your app, and handle the reporting in the `handle_errors` function of the plug, as shown in that documentation page.

Comment: It's just for controller. What about global OTP handling?

Comment: So you want to track all exceptions thrown by any function in any process in the VM?